# Scrollable Div, which elements can be seen

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, position

We have a scrollable div that has CSS `hieght:40px;`. Inside it are multiple LI `height:20px`

```
    <div id="#scroller">
<li title="I1">item1</li>
<li title="I2">item2</li>
<li title="I3">item3</li>
<li title="I4">item4</li>
<li title="I5">item5</li>
<li title="I6">item6</li>
<li title="I7">item7</li>
<li title="I8">item8</li>
<li title="I9">item9</li>
    </div>
```

When the user scrolls I want to trigger a script that determines the first of the two elements which is visible. The div scroll is designed to snap to elements. So if you scroll down and item3 and item 4 are visible how do I fund out that item 3 is the top visible element.

I tried `$('#scroller li:visible')` but this does not work as far as the div is concerned they are all visible just hidden behind their container.

Any ideas,

Marvellous

Comment: you need a combination of `scrollTop` scroller `height` and the item[li] height to calculate it [mathematically]

Comment: oh yes, and `offset().top` in jquery / credit to @doctormick :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Update

Updated with a working example http://jsfiddle.net/U4qyp/32/

---

I think `.position()` should do the job. It gives you the position of the element relative to its parent element. After you called .position() you can access the element coordinates using the properties `top` and `left`.

http://api.jquery.com/position/

The element whose top position plus its height is major than zero, is visible.

Here is an example of what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/U4qyp/10/

Comment: Many thanks, good. I've modifed it slightly http://jsfiddle.net/U4qyp/57/ . Problem is I want it to get an attribute from the element. Since we have it already there how would I get the .html() of the element rather than its sequential numbers

Comment: Good job, thought in your example I think you forgot the opening of the <ul> tag element!

Comment: One problem still. I have the function run through a CSS3 scroll library for touch devices called iScroll4. Fully functional now in Safari and Chrome but firefox does not like it. Just setting up a fiddle

Comment: take a look at this Fiddle. Uses iScroll for mobile platforms. It will work only in Safari and Chrome, Firefox will not work out the position and IE is a write off http://jsfiddle.net/U4qyp/75/

Comment: I checked the source code of that plugin and found there are many callback functions avaiable, for example onScrollEnd(). You should specify in the plugin options, onScrollEnd( function() { // your scrolling function here... }); so that when the scroll ends your function will be called and check for the visible elements.

Comment: Brilliant, but still struggling on Firefox. Firefox does not like the position and keeps defaulting to element 2. Try your fiddle on there

Comment: The jsfiddle is not working any more, can you update it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd have thought the best way to do it is in your scroll event capture the scrollTop value of the div and compare it to the top of each li element (maybe add the height so you can see if the element is completely out of view).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `position` method gets the position relative to the container, and you can get the top position by doing `$("li").position().top;`

So my solution was to write a loop to go through all the elements and find the one with the smallest value for `position().top` and pick that out. Here's the script I wrote:

```
$(function() {

    var mostVisibleItem = $("li:first");

    var smallestOffset = mostVisibleItem.position().top;
    $("li").each(function(i, item) {
        if($(item).position().top < smallestOffset)
        {
            smallestOffset = $(item).position().top;
            mostVisibleItem = $(item);
        }
    });
    mostVisibleItem.css("color", "red");
});
```

You can see this working in JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/P69y2/

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work, where you would replace the console.log with your display logic.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#scroller').scroll(function() {
            $('#scroller li').each(function() {
                if ($(this).position().top > 0) {
                    console.log($(this).html());
                    return false;  // break once the first displayable value has been returned.
                }   
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```